# Ошибка при поиске подстроки регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Работаю в Visual Studio Express 2012.

Здесь можно скачать триальную версию: http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=34673

Написал функцию, которая успешно проверяет строку регулярным выражением и находит нужные подстроки, но когда функция получает остаток строки, в котором уже нет ничего, что бы подходило про выражение, я получаю ошибку:

> Expression: string iterator not dereferencable

Вызов в данной ситуации получается такой:

```
std::smatch m;
std::regex rExp("[a-z][a-z0-9]*"); //имя переменной
strBuf = "*10.5)*51E-10";
std::regex_search (strBuf, m, rExp);
```

Соответственно, ошибка возникает после вызова regex_search.
Причем, при вызове из тела программы всё выполняется успешно, но внутри функции с абсолютно аналогичными аргументами я получаю ошибку в этой строке:

```
while (std::regex_search (strBuf, m, rExp)){
```

Исходный код: http://pastebin.com/6Q3wJ6FD

Если `std::regex` не объявляется по переменной, можете убрать `switch` и писать напрямую:

```
std::regex rExp("[a-z][a-z0-9]*");
```

А в main оставить один вызов `searchLexemes(input, i, 1, fout);`

Comment: А как вы создаёте strBuf?

Comment: std::string strBuf;

Comment: @InfernumDeus, дайте законченный фрагмент кода, в котором проявляется ошибка.

Comment: Процедура заменяет подстроки определённого типа на идентификаторы http://pastebin.com/PPzYqp1h

Comment: @InfernumDeus, у Вас в `std::string IntToString(int a)` типичная ошибка (проявляется при `a = INT_MIN` т.е 0x80000000). Этот случай надо рассматривать отдельно. 

Если нужно, то пример (идею) можно посмотреть [здесь](http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C).

--

А вообще-то, я бы не использовал регэкспы для лексического анализатора. 

Достаточно посимвольно обрабатывать текст и иногда возвращать последний символ (первый символ следующей лексемы) во "входной поток".

Comment: Уже слышал про такой метод, но по заданию требуется сделать это именно так.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, "именно так" -- это значит требуется обязательно использовать регулярные выражения?

Тогда либо установите верию С++, которая это поддерживает,  
либо используйте регэкспы из Си (`man 3 regexec`).

Comment: @avp, спасибо, поищу другую среду. Можно считать это принятым ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Говоря *законченный фрагмент*, я имел в виду код вместе с исходными данными, который можно откомпилировать и увидеть ошибку
(без этого, по крайней мере нужен код, вызывающий `searchLexemes()` и устанавливающий ее аргументы).

Крайне желательно выложить не весь Ваш проект, а минимальную законченную часть, воспроизводящую ошибку.

Кстати, весьма вероятно, что работая над созданием такого фрагмента, Вы самостоятельно выявите ошибку.

**Обновление**

Да, не  работает. Более того, у меня:

```
Linux avp-xub11 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8  19:35:44 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
...
g++ tst.cpp -std=c++11 -g
```

валится на `std::regex rExp(strBuf);`, причем, независимо в main или внутри функции и даже пример из http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/ не работает (валиться на первом же образце с `[ ]`).

---

Обычный (для Си) regcomp/regexec, естественно работает (как ему и положено).

Интересно, а у кого нибудь в крестах работает?

Comment: Убрал всё лишнее http://pastebin.com/6Q3wJ6FD

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @avp: [c++11 regex реализовано достаточно полно только в gcc 4.9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20027305). Про Visual Studio соответствие c++11 стандарту, можно у гугла спросить.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос по этому поводу.